# paste several words in the name of a file text in R

Tags: r, filenames, paste

I want to create a series of file txt, called "matrix_i.arp". Wherein "i" can assume values from 1 to 5.

```
for (i in 1:5) {
writeLines(txt, paste("matrix", i, sep="_"))
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to paste ".arp" to the name of each file txt.

Comment: `paste0("matrix_", i,".arp")`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is what I was looking for.